# Listview to textview

Tags: c#, android

I want to when i'm clicking one item in my list view to send the in a textview
I'm using this code but nothing happens

```
listview1.ItemClick += listview1_SetOnClickListener;
}

void listview1_SetOnClickListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextView textview1= FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PanelCaptionSelect);
ListView listView1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.PanelCaptions);
String list;
list = listView1.SelectedItem.ToString();

textview1.Text = list;
```

Comment: [ListView Interactivity - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#selectiontaps) might point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for answer but didnt helped

Comment: Is the value supposed to be in 'textview5' the right one?

Comment: `to send the in a textview` ??? To send what?

Comment: Yes i want to bring selected listview value in a textview

Comment: What is a listview value?

Comment: I dont see an onClick listener function.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
lvDetail.ItemClick += (object sender,   Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
{

string selectedFromList = lvDetail.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();
lbltext.Text = selectedFromList;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!